# USB game controller not detected

Tags: usb, compatibility

Since upgrading my version of OSX, my computer no longer detects a USB game controller.  I know the controller is in working order because my Linux machine can talk to it.  I don't know which version broke it, but I have photo evidence of the controller working about a year ago and I'm currently running 10.11.3 (Mid 2014 MBP).  I can't divine anything useful out of `/Applications/Utilities/System Information`, maybe you can.

**How do I debug the onset of incompatibility with my USB game controller?**

Comment: Could you supply the specific model of USB game controller? As asked it's a bit too vague.

Comment: I can't.  It's internal to a custom-built controller.  Perhaps Linux can get at exactly what the model is.

Comment: Does it use a common chipset or USB controller found in other game controllers? (edit: I think I can answer this -- see my answer below)

Comment: Can you supply a screenshot of System Information's USB tree?

Comment: @JMY1000 http://i.imgur.com/e8GayWL.png

Comment: @jimmy0x52 @JMY1000 also `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` -> https://pastee.org/yt49k

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the answer [from this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170105/list-usb-devices-on-osx-command-line) to debug your USB devices. If it doesn't even show up there I'd assume the issue was on the controller's end. If it does show up there, it might tell you something about the controller that could help identify where the problem lies.